# How to change the "Publisher display name" of an extension on Microsoft Edge Add-ons?

Tags: microsoft-edge, browser-extension, microsoft-edge-extension, browser-addons, microsoft-edge-chromium

I have an extension on Microsoft Edge Add-ons. I have a question about changing the "Publisher display name". I want to change the language of my "Publisher display name".

- What is the right way to do that?
- Will it be an additional round of
  review?

Answer (score 2):

To Update your Publisher display name or address on Partner Center:

1. Go to **Settings**, **Account settings** and **select Organization profile**.
2. Select Legal and then select the **update** next to **Contact Info** you want to update.
3. Click on Save to confirm and change the details.

Once you change any of your contact details such as **Publisher display name (Company name)**, the Microsoft Edge extension team may verify your account again, especially if you have a company account.

Your verification status returns to `Pending` while the review is in process.  The verification process ranges from a few days to a couple of weeks, and your company may receive a phone call from our verification partner.

To reflect the changes on the Edge add-ons though, you will need to submit an update, either the package update or metadata update, to your extension on Partner Center.

Hope this information helps! Thank you!

Comment: Hey, by any chance, do you know how to change the account status from Individual to Company? Currently, next to Account Details, it says "Redeem code" to expand capabilities for editing. MS support is not responding as expected.

How to obtain the "Redeem code"?